# Send & cancel button do not work on Unity Facebook AppRequest dialog

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using Unity 5.4.0 and Facebook SDK 7.8.0.
I have a problem when touching send or cancel button on Facebook AppRequest dialog on Galaxy Note 2(Android 4.3).
Actually there's no problem with other devices I have and the close button works either.

When I touch the send or cancel button, there's an exception like

```
08-19 04:06:17.731: W/ActivityManager(2429): Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
08-19 04:06:17.741: E/DatabaseUtils(2429): Writing exception to parcel
08-19 04:06:17.741: E/DatabaseUtils(2429): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
08-19 04:06:17.741: E/DatabaseUtils(2429):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13192)
08-19 04:06:17.741: E/DatabaseUtils(2429):  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2044)
08-19 04:06:17.741: E/DatabaseUtils(2429):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:615)
08-19 04:06:17.741: E/DatabaseUtils(2429):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
08-19 04:06:17.741: E/DatabaseUtils(2429):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
08-19 04:06:17.741: E/DatabaseUtils(2429):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
08-19 04:06:17.741: E/DatabaseUtils(2429):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

and the buttons don't seem like touched and do nothing.
It happens not all the time but in some cases.

Is there any one who knows why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

According to exception you need to add permission `android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` to your android manifest file.

You can find manifest file in `Assets/Plugins/Android`directory.

Have you tried to do this?

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried that but there's no difference, and same exception.

Comment: And as I said, not always but sometimes. I know it will be more useful if I can explain the cases but it's too complicated to explain. (It's like turning cameras on and off to achieve a scene transition like system.)